# Implied meaning of ordering types in C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, spaceship-operator

C++20 allows users to specify different return types when defining `operator <=>`: `std::partial_ordering`, `std::weak_ordering` and `std::strong_ordering`. Does specifying them imply that corresponding class promises to obey certain [ordering axioms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)? E.g. for partial ordering those would be [irreflexivity, asymmetry and transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#strict_partial_order).

I couldn't find any mentions of this in C++20 standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely the intent of categories.

All the orderings should be irreflexive, asymetric, and transitive. `weak_ordering` and `strong_ordering` should be total orders. `strong_ordering` implies substitutability (i.e. that `a == b` implies `f(a) == f(b)`, for a collection of functions `f` for which this question makes sense -- for instance `std::addressof` is not one such function).

This isn't in the C++ standard because it's not really a matter of the rules of the language - it's a matter of what you should or should not do as a programmer. Like if you declare `operator<=>` that returns `strong_ordering`, it should absolutely be a valid ordering that satisfies substitutability - but that's, at best, maybe a note, and would feel out of place in the rest of the document.

But you can read more of the original ordering papers to get a sense of intent, like [P0100](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0100r2.html) and [P0515](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf).

Comment: "it's a matter of what you should or should not do as a programmer" - at least for algorithms library standard [clearly states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/alg.sorting) that `Compare` should be a strict weak ordering and lists its axioms in detail. Why is spaceship operator different? At the moment all the `XXX_ordering` types look nothing more than a bunch of fancy words without solid mathematical requirements :(

Comment: (I'd be glad to be wrong)

Comment: @yugr The algorithms have requirements for how `<` needs to behave, but the _language_ doesn't say anything about what a  `bool operator<(T, T)` should mean. We don't have any three-way comparison algorithms yet - when we add those, then you'll see similar language in that section.